# Is this implementation of Task.Factory.FromAsync actually running async

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, async-await

I tested from a WinForm since I heard Console apps lie about `async` stuff :

```
List<string> lstFiles = new List<string>();         
lstFiles = FillList();   // File list with all files to Process                
List<PSObject> lstRetVals = new List<PSObject>();

try
{
    foreach (string strFullFile in lstFiles)
    { lstRetVals.AddRange(clsOne.TestFifteen(strFullFile)); }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{throw ex ;}
```

This intermediary method is basically just here because I was testing proper use of await. It appears that not using await and blocking is best for my use..

```
        //public async Task<int> TestFifteen(string  pStrFullFilePathFileNm)    
    // as you see from this previous Signature
      public List<PSObject> TestFifteen(string pStrFullFilePathFileNm)            
    {         
        int iRetVal = -99;
        Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> tRetval = null;
        List<PSObject> lstPsObjs = null;
        try
        {
            tRetval = TestFifteenSub(pStrFullFilePathFileNm);
            lstPsObjs = tRetval.Result.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception zz)
        { throw zz; }

        //  Debug.WriteLine("Is this OK");

        foreach (PSObject psobj in tRetval.Result)
        {
            iRetVal = tRetval.Result.Count;
            // return  Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>>  or   
        }
        //return iRetVal;
        return lstPsObjs;
    }
```

And finally the area of concern : ----Task.Factory.FromAsync----  I have to use this as there is no TAP implementation for the Powershell API yet.. So is this line actually Async? ACTUALLY STARTING a new thread?

```
public Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> TestFifteenSub(string p_scriptText)
    {
        //var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddScript(p_scriptText);
        Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> plpl;
        PSDataCollection<PSObject> psDtaColOfpsDtaObjs = null;
        List<PSObject> lstPSObjs = null;

        try
        {
            plpl = Task.Factory.FromAsync(ps.BeginInvoke(), pResult => ps.EndInvoke(pResult)); //  BLOCKS here No await Keyword so it waits for this call to complete
            //await taskQue;        
            psDtaColOfpsDtaObjs = plpl.Result;
            lstPSObjs = plpl.Result.ToList();
            //  lstPSObjs = convertedObject.ToList();
        }

        catch (Exception vv)
        { throw vv; }

        // return plpl.Result;           
        return plpl;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it is blocking on that line and not `psDtaColOfpsDtaObjs = plpl.Result;`? Also, Async does not mean "start a thread" it means "Do work in background", often the way the work is done does not involve threads but instead involves waiting for IO to complete or waiting for a event to fire.

Answer (score 3):

> I tested from a WinForm since I heard Console apps lie about async stuff

It's true that the *console* APIs for reading and writing *to the console* do not correctly use asynchronous implementations, but that won't affect any other APIs. The only other catch with asynchronous consoles is that you have to have a single top-level blocking call so the main thread doesn't exit.

> It appears that not using await and blocking is best for my use

If you're writing a console application, then blocking is OK. You may want to reevaluate this if you're writing a winforms application; `async` is useful to keep the UI thread free.

> So is this line actually Async? ACTUALLY STARTING a new thread?

As others have commented, asynchronous methods (generally) do not start new threads. In fact, it's the opposite of that: asynchronous methods *free up the calling thread*. And yes, it's asynchronous.

That said, calling an asynchronous method and then immediately *blocking* on the returned task (by calling `Task<T>.Result`) is rather pointless, since `PowerShell` also has a synchronous `Invoke` method. If you're going to block anyway, then you may as well call the synchronous method.

In fact, if you're always blocking, why use `async` and `await` at all? You should just use synchronous method.

```
public PSDataCollection<PSObject> TestFifteenSub(string p_scriptText)
{
  PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
  ps.AddScript(p_scriptText);
  return ps.Invoke();
}

public List<PSObject> TestFifteen(string pStrFullFilePathFileNm)            
{         
  PSDataCollection<PSObject> retval = null;
  List<PSObject> lstPsObjs = null;

  retval = TestFifteenSub(pStrFullFilePathFileNm);
  lstPsObjs = retval.ToList();

  return lstPsObjs;
}
```

Comment: thanks all... as you may have noticed at the middle method TestFifteen() and its earlier signature version  I'm just testing here as I --MIGHT-- need to use the await keyword either at TestFifteen()  or back at that form level method where the loop is.   I'm doing ugly IO then firing up instances of an exe all with PowerShell and some or all of those tasks may need separate threads

Comment: `In fact, if you're always blocking, why use async and await at all? You should just use synchronous method.` @StephenCleary Is this still true in ASP.net? I'm writing a Web API project which uses runspaces, and I am using `Task.Factory.FromAsync` with powershell, and immediately `await`ing. My route is `async`. My understanding that with asp.net this is still preferable because it allows better management of the thread pool; am I off-base?

Comment: @briantist: No, that's correct; your code should be using `await`. In this case, the op is not using `await`; he's using `Result`, which completely negates the point of asynchronous code.